# Problem in understanding the proof of a theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I can not understand the proof of Theorem 4 on page 2 of [this document](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~frank/0413/ullimits.pdf).

> **Theorem 4:** Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence with lower and upper limits $\underline{x}$ and $\overline{x}$,
>   respectively. There are subsequences of $(x_n)$ converging to $\underline{x}$ and to $\overline{x}$.
>
> **Proof:** We will prove the assertion for the upper limit. The assertion for the lower limit is similar.
>
> We construct a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ inductively so that
>   $$
> \left|x_{n_k} − \overline{x}\right| <\frac{1}{k}.
> $$
>
> By Lemma 3, there is an $n_1\in \Bbb N$ such that $$\left|x_{n_1} − \overline{x}\right| < 1.$$ Now suppose $n_1,\dots, n_k$ have been chosen. By Lemma 3, there is an $n_{k+1} > n_k$
>   such that $$|x_{n_{k+1}} − \overline{x}| <\frac{1}{k+1},$$
>   which completes the inductive step. Finally, it follows from (3) and the Squeeze Theorem that
>   $$x_{n_k}\to\overline{x},$$
>   which completes the proof.

I do not understand how it follows from Lemma 3 that there is $n_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_{n_1}-\overline{x}|<1$.

I also do not understand how it follows from Lemma 3 that there is an $n_{k+1}>n_k$ such that $|x_{n_{k+1}}-\overline{x}|<\frac{1}{k+1}$.
Can someone kindly explain it to me?

Comment: Can you explain what in particular you don't understand?

Comment: @Stahl: I edited my question on specific details of what I do not understand.

Comment: With $\varepsilon=1$ what Lemma 3 says?

Comment: @MyGlasses: It says for every $K\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $n>K$ such that $|x_n-\overline{x}|<1$.

Comment: Say for instanse $n_1$. With $\varepsilon=\dfrac12$ what Lemma 3 says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemma 3 says the following: "Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence with lower and upper limits $\underline{x}$ and $\overline{x}$, respectively. For every $\epsilon > 0$ and every $K\in\Bbb N$ there are $m, n > K$ such that
$|x_m − \underline{x}| < \epsilon$ and $|x_n − \overline{x}| < \epsilon$."

To find $n_1$, let $\epsilon = 1 > 0$ and let $K = 1$. Then the lemma says that there exists $n > 1 = K$ such that $\left|x_n - \overline{x}\right| < 1$. Let this $n$ be your $n_1$. You can do this because you know lemma 3 holds for *any* $\epsilon > 0$, and $1$ is certainly greater than $0$. You can also find $n$ for *any* $K\in\Bbb N$, and $1\in\Bbb N$.

Next, to find $n_{k+1}$ given $n_1,\dots, n_k$, let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{k+1} > 0$ and let $K = n_k$. Lemma 3 then tells you that there is an $n > n_k = K$ such that $\left|x_n - \overline{x}\right| < \frac{1}{k+1}$. You can take this $n$ to be your $n_{k+1}$. Again, the lemma allows this, because $\epsilon = \frac{1}{k+1} > 0$ and $K = n_k\in\Bbb N$ and the lemma applies to any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $K\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: But why $n_{k+1} > n_k$.? this finish your answer.

Comment: @MyGlasses What do you mean? The lemma gave me $n > n_k$ with the desired property, and setting $n_{k+1} = n$ gives $n_{k+1} > n_k$.

Comment: I have a question. In lemma 3, there was big $K$ but in the proof of theorem 4 there is small $k$. so do we in the first step have $k=K=1$?

Comment: @user17797 Yes, but for $K = 1$ this is the case only because we need a base case (the proof of theorem 4 is essentially by induction on $k$). Since $1$ is the smallest element of $\Bbb N$, it was the natural choice for $K$ (although we could have taken any $K\in\Bbb N$ to start). At step $2$, you take $K$ to be $n_1$, which was obtained in the first step, and there is no reason for this to be equal to $2$.

Comment: @Stahl: Thanks a lot. I appreciate the time and effort you spent to help me.